# Cannot find module from 'node_modules/.pnpm/../dist/index.js' error when use package

Tags: node.js, typescript2.0, tsconfig

How I can configure the a package that bundled with sub package? I configure my package as following and run test without any problem. However, when I tried to use the `package_name` in some other repo after `pnpm i package_name` and run the test. I see the error
`Cannot find module 'dependency_package' from 'node_modules/.pnpm/package_name/dist/index.js'` and the error is cleared out after I manually install `dependency_package`. How should I set up my package `package_name` so I do not need to manually install `dependency_package`?

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "package_name",
  "version": "0.0.0t",
  "description": "testing wrap packageg",
  "author": "abc<abc@xyz.com>",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "repository": "https://github.com/xyz/abc.git",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "engines": {
    "hnvm": "16.13.2",
    "pnpm": "6.31.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ts-node/register test/*.ts && tslint **/*.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dependency_package": "1.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "mocha": "^9.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "dependency_package": "1.0.0"
  }
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ]
}


// index.ts
import subPackageFunction from 'dependency_package';

export default function defaultFunction(object: any[]): string {
  return subPackageFunction(object);
}

// test/index.spec.ts
import {expect} from 'chai';

import subPackageFunction from '../src/dependency_package';

describe('Main Test', () => {
  it('returns example', () => {
    expect(defaultFunction([{}])).equal([{}]);
  });
```